# How to access account address for local development in Mist Wallet?

Tags: web3js, mist

I'm trying to develop a DApp and test it using the Mist wallet. When I navigate to `localhost:8000` in the Mist browser and open up the Dev Console, `web3.eth.accounts` returns an empty array. I know I have an account because I can see it in my Mist wallet. How do I access this account in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible option I've found so far: you can request access to an account from Mist

```
mist.requestAccount(function (err, walletAddress) {
  // use wallet address here
})
```